# how get variation title using wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I will create a dropdown using options can be displayed the varaiation_id and variation_title, I have to get some other details of variation like variation_is_active,variation_is_visible etc.but i don't get  variation title please give me answer, here show the code

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_contents' ); 
global $product;
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
$variations =$product->get_available_variations();
foreach($product->get_variation_attributes() as $ind=>$val)
{
echo  $ind;

}
?>
$field_name = isset($field_name) ? $field_name :'';
$calendar_id = isset($calendar_id) ? $calendar_id : 0;
if ( $field_name ):?>
<select data-calendar-id="<?php echo $calendar_id ?>" name="<?php echo 
esc_attr($field_name); ?>" >
<?php else: ?>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php foreach ($variations as $variation_id => $variation_data): ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $variation_data['variation_id'] ?>" ><?php 
    echo str_replace('-', '',substr($variation_data['variation_title'],15)) ?> 
    </option>

<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Variation Product doesn't' have title on there own they use their parent Title .

if you want to get the title of the parent product you can use  `get_the_title()` or if you want to append some html code for the tittle you can use `the_title();`  inside of your loop.

for more information about those two functions check the following links:

[Reference get_the_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/)

[Reference the_title](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the WC_Product_Variation_Class https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product_Variation.html

Then you can use;

```
$product->get_title( )

Get the product's title. For variations this is the parent product name.
```